# Network Class Loader for IronRuby / Dynamic Language Runtime?

Tags: c#, dynamic-language-runtime

As it is now, I can load a local file:

```
engine.ExecuteFile("c:/myclass.rb");
```

But the DLR throws an exception with this:

```
 engine.ExecuteFile("ftp://localhost/myclass.rb");
```

And I'm sure that if it can't even do this, then it probably can't load classes over the network automatically either.

Does anyone know how to have the DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime) load classes over the network?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct - it can only load files from a path resolvable via "standard file open" calls - so a path starting with `ftp://` does not conform to that definition... for further reference see MSDN for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seshadripv/archive/2008/07/28/various-ways-to-execute-script-using-the-dlr-hosting-api.aspx and http://dlr.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Docs%20and%20specs&referringTitle=Documentation